# Username and password storage location

Tags: vb.net, registry, isolatedstorage, password-storage

I am writing a program in vb.net that requires a user to log in before he can use the application. The main user is created when the program is installed, similar to how windows works when it is installed.

The main user can add additional users to the program. I already know that I should store the passwords encrypted. My question is, where should I store the usernames and passwords? The registry, Isolated storage or .config file. I don't want any user to be able to modify/delete that file as the other user would obviously not be able to log in. Also, this file should be accessible for any user that logs into the computer.

The computer is not guaranteed to be connected to the internet, so it must be stored locally.

Thanks

Comment: Another option is to validate users based on their *Windows* login credentials. That way, you let Windows handle storing the user names and passwords for you.

Comment: Does the application utilize any kind of storage back end such as a database?  Also, is this application itself networked in any way?  In other words - if the application is installed on two machines are you expecting the users / passwords to be synced?

Comment: I have thought about that, but it is not a viable solution for the environment where my program would be used.

Comment: @RQDQ No, it is not connected to a database and it is only on a single computer. It is a security program and different operators must be able to log in. It is therefore important to know which operator was logged in when certain events occur. Some of the users will be administrators. They will be able to make changes to the program. Operators won't be able to make changes to the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to use windows users/credentials in any way on the machine, then there really is no absolute way to prevent the file from being removed/changed, Since anyone on the computer has the same access as the main user, who needs rights to modify the file in order for him to add users through the program.

The only way to do it for sure is to have the main user logon with a different user name, and set the file permissions on that file/folder to make sure that only the main user has modify permission to the file (and the other user account does not have the right to modify permissions). I know you said it wouldn't work in your environment(which is?)  but you might be able to create users and run stuff under different credentials through your code without having the users log on any different.

The only crazy way I can think of is to create a service on the computer that once it starts running, it opens and holds a handle to that file with sharing set such that no other process can open the file for writing. You'd of course have to workout some way for the main user to be able to add users.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have decided that the file would be created during installation. If it is not there when the program is loaded, the program will go into lock down. The only way to get it back then would be to uninstall the program and re-install it.

Answer (score 2):

To tell you the truth if someone has the will power to look for the file they will find it, so storage can help up security but I would focus on the contents of the file itself.

You could try to store the data of the application as a encrypted file which could stop the amateur attempts but as you are using the .net framework your program could could be decompiled and any symmetric encryption algorithms could be rendered useless.

I think your best bet would be to either generate a seed according to the computer the program is on, and if decryption fails call home or go into Lock Down.

Another option would be to store the encrypted (encrypted with your symmetric key) file and a hash file (in different locations probably). If the hash of the loaded file then does not match the hash file your program could then call home (If you have a home to call).

**This is just a idea, haven't actually tried anything like this.**

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. At first I will go into lock down if the file is not found. My main priority is that a user won't accidentally delete the file. Would isolated storage be the best/easiest solution for this? Would this file still be accessible for any user that logs into the computer?

Comment: I haven't used Isolated storage but from what I gather from - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.80).aspx - is that the path include a <user> which could mean that it's per user. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, as I have never used isolated storage.

Comment: Yeah, I've read a bit now about isolated storage and it does not seem like the best choice. I think I'll save it in the registry

Comment: Make sure you salt your hash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 Also - for the love of god leave it out of the registry.  There is no intrinsic benefit to putting it in the registry and the registry is an antiquated concept that is only still with us because of legacy applications.